# ProviderNotFoundException was thrown building Consumer(dirty): Error: Could not find the correct Provider above this Consumer Widget

Tags: flutter, flutter-provider

I'm new to Flutter and I'm trying to use providers to manage the state of my app but I get this error:

══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY WIDGETS LIBRARY ╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following ProviderNotFoundException was thrown building Consumer(dirty):
Error: Could not find the correct Provider above this Consumer
Widget

This happens because you used a `BuildContext` that does not include the provider
of your choice. There are a few common scenarios:

- You added a new provider in your `main.dart` and performed a hot-reload.
  To fix, perform a hot-restart.
- The provider you are trying to read is in a different route.

  Providers are "scoped". So if you insert of provider inside a route, then
  other routes will not be able to access that provider.
- You used a `BuildContext` that is an ancestor of the provider you are trying to read.

  Make sure that Consumer is under your MultiProvider/Provider.
  This usually happens when you are creating a provider and trying to read it immediately.

  For example, instead of:

  ```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Provider<Example>(
      create: (_) => Example(),
      // Will throw a ProviderNotFoundError, because `context` is associated
      // to the widget that is the parent of `Provider<Example>`
      child: Text(context.watch<Example>()),
    ),
  }
  ```

  consider using `builder` like so:

  ```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Provider<Example>(
      create: (_) => Example(),
      // we use `builder` to obtain a new `BuildContext` that has access to the provider
      builder: (context) {
        // No longer throws
        return Text(context.watch<Example>()),
      }
    ),
  }
  ```

Here is my main.dart:

```
import 'package:app_alimentazione/Pagine/pagina_alimenti.dart';
import 'package:app_alimentazione/Providers/json_list_provider.dart';
import 'package:app_alimentazione/Providers/lists_provider.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'Pagine/pagina_principale.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        FutureProvider(
            create: (context) => JsonListProvider().jsonData,
            initialData: []),
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => ListsProvider())
      ],
      builder: (context, child) {

          return Consumer<JsonListProvider>(
            builder: (context, jsonList, child){ 
            return MaterialApp(
              theme: ThemeData(
                primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
              ),
              home: PaginaAlimenti(jsonList:jsonList.jsonData),
            );}
          );
     
      },
    );
  }
}
```

And here is my FirstPage:

```
import 'package:app_alimentazione/Classi/alimento.dart';
import 'package:app_alimentazione/Providers/lists_provider.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

class PaginaAlimenti extends StatelessWidget {
  final Future<List<Alimento>>? jsonList;
  const PaginaAlimenti({Key? key, this.jsonList}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Consumer<ListsProvider>(
      builder: (context, lists, child) {
      lists.mainList = jsonList;
      return ListView.builder(
          itemCount: lists.mainList.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return Card(
              child: Text(lists.mainList[index].nome!),
            );
          });
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Here: `create: (context) => JsonListProvider().jsonData()`, are you sure that you need `.jsonData()` as well? Shouldn't it be just `create: (context) => JsonListProvider()`?

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I followed this example: [link](https://flutterbyexample.com/lesson/future-provider)

Comment: I see, but then you don't need `JsonListProvider().jsonData()`, but `JsonListProvider().jsonData`, to pass the function instead of executing it.

Comment: Oh, you are right. I fixed that but I get the same error.

Comment: What type does `JsonListProvider().jsonData` return? `Consumer<JsonListProvider>` might be not correct, because here after `Consumer` you should have the type that is returned by the future. For example if you have a `FutureProvider<String>` then it should be `Consumer<String>`.

Comment: JsonListProvider().jsonData return a Future<List<Alimento>>. Alimento is an object created by me. I tried writing like this:<br/>[code]    return Consumer<Future<List<Alimento>>><br/> but nothing changes

Comment: And what about `Consumer<List<Alimento>>`?

Comment: Same error. Can it be a hierarchy issue?

Comment: Even if you declare the provider like: `FutureProvider<List<Alimento>>`?

Comment: Thank you very much. It works now.

Comment: Good to hear, I`ve started to run out of ideas...

Comment: Hey @Ice If you put in a little of your time to provide how you fixed the issue as an answer it will be very important for you and the rest of the people coming here. Thanks.